# How to change the "All Categories" label within the panel of my custom post type?

Tags: customization

I just created a custom post type and a custom taxonomy:

```
// === CUSTOM TAXONOMIES === //
add_action('init', 'my_custom_taxonomies', 0);

function my_custom_taxonomies() {
    register_taxonomy(
        'location',     // internal name = machine-readable taxonomy name
        'static_content',       // object type = post, page, link, or custom post-type
        array(
            'hierarchical' => true,
            'labels' => array(
                'name' => __( 'Location' ),
                'singular_name' => __( 'Location' ),
                'add_new_item' => 'Add New Location',
                'edit_item' => 'Edit Location',
                'new_item' => 'New Location',
                'search_items' => 'Search Location',
                'not_found' => 'No Location found',
                'not_found_in_trash' => 'No Location found in trash',
            ),
            'query_var' => true,    // enable taxonomy-specific querying
            'rewrite' => array( 'slug' => 'location' ), // pretty permalinks for your taxonomy?
        )
    );

    wp_insert_term('Footer', 'location');
    wp_insert_term('Header', 'location');
}


// === CUSTOM POST TYPES === //
add_action( 'init', 'create_my_post_types' );

function create_my_post_types() {
    register_post_type( 'static_content',
        array(
            'labels' => array(
                'name' => __( 'Static Content' ),
                'singular_name' => __( 'Static Content' ),
                'add_new_item' => 'Add New Static Content',
                'edit_item' => 'Edit Static Content',
                'new_item' => 'New Static Content',
                'search_items' => 'Search Static Content',
                'not_found' => 'No Static Content found',
                'not_found_in_trash' => 'No Static Content found in trash',
            ),
            '_builtin' => false,
            'public' => true,
            'hierarchical' => false,
            'taxonomies' => array( 'location'),
            'supports' => array(
                'title',
                'editor',
                'excerpt'
            ),
            'rewrite' => array( 'slug' => 'static_content', 'with_front' => false )
        )
    );
}
```

But when I enter the edit page of my custom post type, on the sidebar it says "All Categories." It should say "All Locations."

How do I change that label?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add this to the `labels` array:

```
'all_items' => __( 'All Locations' ),
```

See [`register_taxonomy()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/register_taxonomy) docs for full description of `labels` argument.